# how do I remove rows/columns from this matrix using python

Tags: python, csv, matrix, numpy, scipy

My matrix looks like this.

```
 ['Hotel', ' "excellent"', ' "very good"', ' "average"', ' "poor"', ' "terrible"', ' "cheapest"', ' "rank"', ' "total reviews"']
 ['westin', ' 390', ' 291', ' 70', ' 43', ' 19', ' 215', ' 27', ' 813']
 ['ramada', ' 136', ' 67', ' 53', ' 30', ' 24', ' 149', ' 49', ' 310 ']
 ['sutton place', '489', ' 293', ' 106', ' 39', ' 20', ' 299', ' 24', ' 947']
 ['loden', ' 681', ' 134', ' 17', ' 5', ' 0', ' 199', ' 4', ' 837']
 ['hampton inn downtown', ' 241', ' 166', ' 26', ' 5', ' 1', ' 159', ' 21', ' 439']
 ['shangri la', ' 332', ' 45', ' 20', ' 8', ' 2', ' 325', ' 8', ' 407']
 ['residence inn marriott', ' 22', ' 15', ' 5', ' 0', ' 0', ' 179', ' 35', ' 42']
 ['pan pacific', ' 475', ' 262', ' 86', ' 29', ' 16', ' 249', ' 15', ' 868']
 ['sheraton wall center', ' 277', ' 346', ' 150', ' 80', ' 26', ' 249', ' 45', ' 879']
 ['westin bayshore', ' 390', ' 291', ' 70', ' 43', ' 19', ' 199', ' 813']
```

I want to remove the top row and the 0th column from this and create a new matrix.

How do I do this?

Normally in java or so Id use the following code:

```
 for (int y; y< matrix[x].length; y++)
     for(int x; x < matrix[Y].length; x++)
      {
        if(x == 0 || y == 0)
         {
           continue
          }
          else
           {
             new_matrix[x][y] = matrix[x][y];
           }


      }
```

Is there a way such as this in python to iterate and selectively copy elements?

Thanks

---

EDIT

Im also trying to convert each matrix element from a string to a float as I iterate over the matrix.

This my updated modified code based on the answer below.

```
A = []
f = open("csv_test.csv",'rt')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        A.append(row)
 finally:
     f.close()

 new_list = [row[1:] for row in A[1:]]
 l = np.array(new_list)
 l.astype(np.float32)
 print l
```

However Im getting an error

```
  --> l.astype(np.float32)
       print l


      ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: The line `l.astype(np.float32)` should read `l = l.astype(np.float32)`.  I don't think that solves your `ValueError`, but `astype` returns a new copy of the array.  It doesn't work in place.

Comment: What values do you get for `l.shape` and `l.dtype`?

Comment: For l.shape I get 10. for l.dtype I get object

Comment: The last row of data is missing an item. See my updated answer for more details.

Comment: If possible: Wherever you get your data from in the first place, load it in a more appropriate way (e.g. using a numpy ndarray)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Basic Idea

Here's what I came up with:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [['hotel','good','bad'],['hilton',1,2],['ramada',3,4]]
>>> a = np.array(l) # convert to a numpy array to make multi-dimensional slicing possible
>>> a
array([['hotel', 'good', 'bad'],
       ['hilton', '1', '2'],
       ['ramada', '3', '4']], 
      dtype='|S4')
>>> a[1:,1:] # exclude the first row and the first column
array([['1', '2'],
       ['3', '4']], 
      dtype='|S4')
>>> a[1:,1:].astype(np.float32) # convert to float
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]], dtype=float32)
```

You can pass your 2d list to the numpy array constructor, slice the 2d array to get rid of the first row and column and then use the [`astype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method to convert everything to a float.

All on one line, that'd be:

```
>>> l = [['hotel','good','bad'],['hilton',1,2],['ramada',3,4]]
>>> np.array(l)[1:,1:].astype(np.float32)
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]], dtype=float32)
```

### The ValueError

You're getting a `ValueError` because you actually have a jagged array.  Using the variable `new_list` from the code in your question you can prove this to yourself:

```
>>> [len(x) for x in new_list]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8]
```

The last row is only of length 8, instead of 9, like all the others.  Given a 2d jagged list, the `numpy.array` constructor will create a 1d numpy array with a `dtype` of `object`.  The entries in that array are Python lists.  The `astype` call is attempting to convert Python lists to `float32`, which is failing.  I'm guessing this was just a case of human error.  If you fix the missing entry, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, however getting an error, I updated my "EDIT" section above. Would appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 5):

If you have a list of lists, then:

```
new_list = [row[1:] for row in current_list[1:]]
```

So, create a new matrix ignoring the first row, and for each row after, ignore the first column.

If it happened to be a `numpy.array`, then you could use:

```
your_array[1:,1:]
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I forgot one thing....., if you could help that would be awesome. Please see EDIT above

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehensions is what you need. Example:

```
def remove_from_matrix(matrix, columns, rows):
    return [
           [float(matrix[row_num][col_num])
           for col_num in range(len(matrix[row_num])) 
           if not col_num in columns]

           for row_num in range(len(matrix))
           if not row_num in rows]
```